# AngularJS show data based on selected category

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, filter

i want to show this accordion based on category that i select from selectBox,
for now it only show all data, but i want to give some filter.
Here is my code and my database.
anyone know how to do it without change any database or using angularUI accordion?

```
 <div class="cs_member_info">
      <select class="cs_member_select">
        <option value="A">Type 1</option>
        <option value="B">Type 2</option>
        <option value="C">Type 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

<div class="cs_body" ng-repeat="cs in csList">  
  <div class="cs_acc_div">
    <button class="cs_accordion" ng-class="{'active': isClicked, 'off' : !isClicked}" ng-click="isClicked = !isClicked">
      <p class="noti_title">
        {{cs.faq.title}}
      </p>
    </button>
    <div class="panel" ng-show="isClicked">
      <p class="panel_inside">
        {{cs.faq.contents}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

    "_id":"59111a018479e30d387be584",
"lang":1,
"type":"FAQ",
"created_at":"2017-05-09T01:23:13.324Z",
"category":{
"code":1,
"name":"Member information"
},
"faq":{
"title":"Login with SNS ID",
"contents":"Login with SNS ID"
}
```

Comment: is the content populated by ng-repeat

Comment: yes, i want to repeat it using ng-repeat

Comment: make a fiddle is easy to remodify@beginnerprogrammer

Comment: Simple then use angular default filter. give the model in the select box. I will post an example.

Comment: there are 2 possible ways, 1st is to use ng-switch if you want to use some directive on html side. 2nd way is to use controller or any js function to do this for you.

Comment: you need to bind a model with your select and then you can use ng-switch directive on html markup. This is the shortest and easiest way to achieve your goal. Otherwise you have to involve your angular controller to show hide the data based on your selection.

Answer (score 0):

Check this as a reference. default angular filter

https://plnkr.co/edit/PpWo28ZO6QNiKEo1K5K7?p=preview

Here it is a table. use accordion to repeat and then filter it

Check this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
  <label>Name only
    <select ng-model="search.name">
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
      <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <br>
  <table id="searchObjResults">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
      <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: i'm a little bit confused. this is the first time i'm using angularJS.
how to repeat option by getting data from database?
as u can see, i need to insert the option based on the "category- name", can you describe it to me?

Comment: you need to have to go through some stuff before starting. check this video. this may give you a kick start about angular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkUN-mJtPQ @beginnerprogrammer